# How to display lower quality background image when lazy loading in swiperjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I using [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com) with lazy loading.

How do I display image in lower quality (otzarreta-forest-bizkaia-spain-thumb.jpg) instead of spinner (loader)? but the image should be a background.

the lower quality image should be loading before the high quality image (data-background).

I have try to change from:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
   <div data-background="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gorbea-natural-park-spain.jpg" class="swiper-lazy"></div>
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
 </div>
```

to:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
   <div data-background="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gorbea-natural-park-spain.jpg" class="swiper-lazy"></div>
   <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"
data-background="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/otzarreta-forest-bizkaia-spain-thumb.jpg"></div>
 </div>
```

Not working.

I looking solution by swiper way, like some attribute or property in options but I can't find any.

How do I solve it?

Comment: 10 seconds to load

Comment: How large is it that it's taking 10 seconds to load? It takes that long even locally? That's ridiculous

Comment: Ya dude, if it's taking 10s to both transfer and load that's crazy. Step 1, since I assume it's some gigantic raw image with huge dimensions that will never be necessary in the real world even viewing on a big screen or something, lower the dimensions of the image down with a resize in photoshop or something. Then throw it through compression like tinyjpg.com (which is free), then try with the new file that should be significantly smaller. 10s for an image even on like a 3G connection is no bueno.

Comment: If it's the image in the example, there's no way that should take 10s, I'm on a pretty fast connection so TTFB is ~60ms and download is ~100ms, that's milliseconds, not seconds, so I'd be curious if there's other factors at play here we don't have visibility towards.

Comment: lets assume this is the case for now. any idea how to solve this problem? is it possible?